# How to extract h2 and h3 titles from news articles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create this web **scraper** that can extract the main title from news articles.

```
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= input('enter the url \n')

r = requests.get(url)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
heading = soup.find_all('h1')
print(heading)
print(str.strip(heading[0].text))
```

This works only for the titles in h1 tags but throwing errors for titles in h2 or h3 tags. How can I modify this code so that it works for h2 and h3 tags as well? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

`BeautifulSoup` is quite flexible, just pass in a [list of tag names](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) you want to find:

```
soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2', 'h3'])
```

You can even do:

```
import re

soup.find_all(re.compile(r"^h\d$"))  # would match "h" followed by a single digit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Alex, that worked, I was able to extract h1 and h2 tags but how can I extract the main title from articles like [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/06/introducing-android-basics-nanodegree.html) where the main title is in h3 tag and date in h2.

Comment: @AmitSingh well, you can locate the date by the class name: `soup.find(class_="date-header").get_text()`, same goes for the article title: `soup.find(class_="post-title").get_text()`.